# Javascript - Search Json Value by Key

Tags: javascript, json, object

For reasons beyond my control, I need to search for the same key value in JSONs with different structures.

I a code that is able to find the value of "valor", and no matter what is the structure of the JSON, there always will be a vendor key somewhere inside it.

By now I have two examples of JSON that I receive:

```
[2,"4:4","ExtraNotification",{"typeModel":"553","serialNumber":"0218-009","vendor":"ABC","version":"4.0.2.14"}]
```

and

```
{"id":"101010c90310","timestamp":"2019-02-18T18:33:35.819925957Z","station":true,"type":"call","action":"ExtraNotification","payload":{"model":"F254A","serialNumber":"1543906","vendor":"EVZ","version":"0.180601","si":"2048188","icid":"89312490184"}}
```

I've tried to map it, to check if the property is undefined or not, nothing worked.

Comment: the first is an array, you will need to loop the results and test each item to see if it's an object that has the key 'vendor'

The second is an object array ( a 'collection' ), you and use map here.

Comment: You can use https://github.com/dchester/jsonpath, that way you can search in different structs

Comment: @RafaelLima I've tried this lib, but it just don't work.

Comment: Please read the usage description of the `json` tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can search through the object or array by key. If the key you're looking for is found, return it. Otherwise pass any objects found along the way back through recursively:

```js
let j = [2,"4:4","ExtraNotification",{"typeModel":"553","serialNumber":"0218-009","vendor":"ABC","version":"4.0.2.14"}]
let j2 = {"id":"101010c90310","timestamp":"2019-02-18T18:33:35.819925957Z","station":true,"type":"call","action":"ExtraNotification","payload":{"model":"F254A","serialNumber":"1543906","vendor":"EVZ","version":"0.180601","si":"2048188","icid":"89312490184"}}

function findKey(obj, key) {
    for ([k, v] of Object.entries(obj)){
        if (k == key) return v
        if (typeof v === 'object' &&  v !== null ){
            let found = findKey(v, key)
            if (found) return found
        }
    }
}

console.log(findKey(j, 'vendor'))
console.log(findKey(j2, 'vendor'))
```

This will act like `find()` and return the first match found via depth first search.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a small piece of recursive code. It works for these inputs:

```
var input = [2,"4:4","ExtraNotification",{"typeModel":"553","serialNumber":"0218-009","vendor":"ABC","version":"4.0.2.14"}, [{ "vendor": "111"}, { "vendor": "222"} ]];
//var input = {"id":"101010c90310", "test": { "test1": { "vendor": "aaa" } }, "timestamp":"2019-02-18T18:33:35.819925957Z","station":true,"type":"call","action":"ExtraNotification","payload":{"model":"F254A","serialNumber":"1543906","vendor":"EVZ","version":"0.180601","si":"2048188","icid":"89312490184"}};

var founds = [];
function search(obj) {
    if (obj instanceof Array) {
        for(var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
            search(obj[i]);
        }
    } else {    
        for(var key in obj) {
            if (key == "vendor") {
                founds.push(obj[key]);
            } else if (typeof obj[key] == "object") {
                search(obj[key]);
            }
        }
    }
};
search(input);
console.log(founds);
// First input:  ["ABC", "111", "222"]
// Second input: ["aaa", "EVZ"]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could skip the `parse` (or `stringify` it back) and search within a string. Nothing bad *should* happen...

```js
const json1 = '{"id":"101010c90310","timestamp":"2019-02-18T18:33:35.819925957Z","station":true,"type":"call","action":"ExtraNotification","payload":{"model":"F254A","serialNumber":"1543906","vendor":"EVZ","version":"0.180601","si":"2048188","icid":"89312490184"}}';
const json2 = '[2,"4:4","ExtraNotification",{"typeModel":"553","serialNumber":"0218-009","vendor":"ABC","version":"4.0.2.14"}]';
const regex = /"vendor":"([a-zA-Z0-9]*)"/;

console.log(regex.exec(json1));
console.log(regex.exec(json2));
```

Comment: Oh, I know him. :)

Comment: Here he comes: `"vendor": {"_name": "Mr. Murphy!!"}`

Comment: I'm assuming the looked for vendor key is a simple value, not an object.

Comment: You're assuming a lot more than that. You're also assuming that the vendor value only consists of alphabetical characters (no punctuation, spacing, accented letters, Greek, quotes,...?)

Comment: True to all of that. And I believe that's mostly right, something identified as "vendor key" rather won't be anything like `"Comment ça va, Comme ci, comme ci, comme ci, comme ça"`. Though `-` and `_` aren't out of the question. Still, modifying the regexp to allow for more characters will still keep the solution simpler than recursively traversing an arbitrary structure.